# Retrieve some data from Firebase and put it on a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

How can I retrieve ***Rute*** data from my Firebase in a `RecyclerView` where ***Sofer*** is equal user display name ?

[image]

This is a part of my Firebase. I tried to do this, but there appeared all data.

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ruteRef = rootRef.child("Rute");
    assert user != null;
    Query query = ruteRef.orderByChild("Sofer").equalTo(user.getDisplayName());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(Model.class, R.layout.card_layout, ViewHolder.class, mRef) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, final int position) {

                    viewHolder.setDetails(getContext(), model.getTaraPlecare(), model.getTaraDestinatie(), model.getSofer(),
                            model.getCapTractor(), model.getRemorca(), model.getNumeleIncarcaturii(), model.getDataPlecare(),
                            model.getOrasPlecare(), model.getOrasDestinatie());
                    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // Intent intent = new Intent(Fridge.this, Show.class);
                            //  startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Eroare", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I retrieve Rute data from my firebase in a recyclerview where Sofer is equal user display name ?

Simply by uisng the following query:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ruteRef = rootRef.child("Rute");
Query query = ruteRef.orderByChild("Sofer").equalTo("userDisplayName");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

And **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: There also appeared all children in CardViews, I edited the question and added the onStart code, maybe I made a mistake.

Comment: No, this is not how you should do it. Use Firebase-UI and pass that query to the `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` object as explained in that answer, right?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to replace your existing structure with:

```
Rute:
    [
        { "Username1": 
           //All your data related to Username
        },
        { "Username2": 
           //All your data related to Username
        },
        { "Username3": 
           //All your data related to Username
        }
    ]
```

Above structure would help you to achieve what you want.